# A little bug in my custom jQuery carousel

Tags: jquery, carousel

I'm creating a custom jQuery carousel and its coming out really well :)

But found a little glitch / bug in it. When you click on Prev / Next like a normal user do, it works fine but when you click on it like a robot with hyper speed, it slides blank spaces.

I'm sharing my code here and also providing the [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/omerblink/4e92fb58/). It would be nice if someone could help me out or give me better suggestions to make it more pro :)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="my_carousel">
    <div class="carousel">
      <ul>
        <li style="background:red;"></li>
        <li style="background:green;"></li>
        <li style="background:blue;"></li>
        <li style="background:purple;"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
#my_carousel {
padding: 0 15px;
position: relative;
height: 100px;
display: inline-block;
}
.carousel {
overflow:hidden;
position: relative;
height: 100px;
}
.carousel ul {
list-style: none;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}
.carousel ul li {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
float: left;
}
.controls {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 0;
margin: -10px 0 0;
width: 100%;
}
.prev {
float: left;
}
.next {
float: right;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.my_carousel = function (defaults) {

    // Default settings
    var settings = $.extend({
        layout: 'hort',
        visible_items: 2,
        item_width: this.find('li').width(),
        reel_width: this.find('li').length
    }, defaults);

    if (settings.layout === 'hort') {

        // Adding Prev/Next links 
        this.find('.carousel').after('<div class="controls"><a href="#" class="prev">&lt;</a><a href="#" class="next">&gt;</a></div>');

        // Setting window / reel /controls width
        this.find('.carousel').width(settings.item_width * settings.visible_items);
        this.find('ul').width(settings.reel_width * settings.item_width);

        // Slide control
        $('.controls a').click(function () {
            var pos = $(this).parents(this).find('ul').offset().left;
            if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
                if (pos >= ((settings.item_width * settings.visible_items) - (settings.reel_width * settings.item_width) + settings.item_width)) {
                    $(this).parents(this).find('ul').animate({
                        left: '-=' + settings.item_width + 'px'
                    }, 200);
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                if (pos <= 0) {
                    $(this).parents(this).find('ul').animate({
                        left: '+=' + settings.item_width + 'px'
                    }, 200);
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

};
})(jQuery);

$('#my_carousel').my_carousel();
```

Comment: did you try disabling the buttons until the animation is done? or is that something that you don't want?

Comment: I have tried it... but it didn't work either... i have used it in the else {} statement... may be i have done it the wrong way... what idea do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is caused by your `if()` statement, which is checking your item's left position.

When you quickly click several times on the previous button (for exemple), left value is still animated and has not reached `0` and the next click is happening again.

Please see a solution I can give you using kind of pagination:

```
//ADDED CODE
var currentIndex = 1;
var totalItem = $('.carousel ul li').length;
var totalIndex = totalItem - 1;



// Slide control
$('.controls a').click(function () {
    var pos = $(this).parents(this).find('ul').offset().left;
    if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {

        //REMOVED
        //if (pos >= ((settings.item_width * settings.visible_items) - (settings.reel_width * settings.item_width) + settings.item_width)) { 
        if (currentIndex != totalIndex) { //ADDED
            $(this).parents(this).find('ul').animate({
                left: '-=' + settings.item_width + 'px'
            }, 200);
            currentIndex++;//ADDED
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {

        //REMOVED
        //if (pos <= 0) {

        if (currentIndex != 1) { //ADDED
            $(this).parents(this).find('ul').animate({
                left: '+=' + settings.item_width + 'px'
            }, 200);
            currentIndex--;//ADDED
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

[Live exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/ymucg8at/)

---

Edit 1:

Since you want to be able to manage number of displayed items, here is the [updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/3zdxxgpb/).
I added `var displayedItems = 4;` to the very top of the code that is used in "Default settings" :

```
// Default settings
    var settings = $.extend({
        layout: 'hort',
        visible_items: displayedItems,
        item_width: this.find('li').width(),
        reel_width: this.find('li').length
    }, defaults);
```

And also used to calculate `totalIndex` :

```
var totalIndex = totalItem-(displayedItems-1);
```

Comment: Thanks EdenSource! the solution you gave works pretty well on the current visible_items which is 2. It will eat one slide if the visible_items is set to 1 and add a blank slide if we set the visible_items to 3

Comment: One solution I got is to make the animation more faster. Just make 200 to 150 on line #28 and #36 http://jsfiddle.net/omerblink/4e92fb58/

Comment: Hi, your fiddle is still creating a blank item on fast clicks. I updated my answer for solution to works for various `visible_items` values.

Comment: Yeah EdenSource, I have checked your solution and you did an awesome job... **THUMBS UP** :)